# How to turn off geany message window by default?

Tags: ubuntu, editor, geany

I use [geany](http://www.geany.org/) to do simple text editing and viewing. But its message window takes half the area and is useless for me. I want to turn it off when I run geany. I know [there is a command option `--no-msgwin` for that](http://www.geany.org/manual/0.18.1/index.html#command-line-options). But how can I tell geany not to show message window if I start geany from right click menu? Is there such a configuration option?

**Solved**: a detailed answer is given here:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/354826/how-to-turn-off-geany-message-window-by-default

Comment: This Question doesn't appear to be about a specific programming problem - You'll probably get a better answer on AskUbuntu http://askubuntu.com/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uncheck `View->Show Message Window` or just drag it so it's so small it virtually disappears. Either way Geany will save the preference and restore it next run.